# Node.js piping http.ClientRequest into fs.createWriteStream with Binary Files leads to corrupted/bloated files

Tags: image, node.js, couchdb

I'm having a weird issue with a Node.js (v0.4.12) module I am working on. It's a CouchDB module, and while I'm pretty sure CouchDB is not the problem here, I'll include it as it may be useful information.

Anyways, I'm writing a wrapper for uploading and downloading attachments with CouchDB. I have the upload part working very well, it's the download part I am having difficulty with.

My test process is this:

1. Upload image file ([`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#http.request), [`fs.createReadStream`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.createReadStream))
2. Download file ([`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#http.request))
3. Save downloaded file to different location for comparison/corruption checking ([`fs.createWriteStream`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.createWriteStream), [`stream.pipe`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/streams.html#stream.pipe))

This works fine with plaintext files, but **binary** files like images behaves differently.

As I mentioned before, the upload appears fine. As I can visit the URL in CouchDB and view the image. (the size matches and it renders the image I uploaded) When I use my module to download the file and save it, the output file is larger than the source file, (50-100% larger) and it cannot be opened by any image editors. (hence, it is "corrupted" somehow)

Am I missing something about Streams when it comes to binary files? I've tried changing the `encoding` on both sides to `"binary"` and `"base64"`, but the output file is still 50% larger than the source. Before I discovered the encoding option, it was set to `"utf8"`, and the output file was 100% larger, so that leads me to think this is an encoding issue somewhere in there.

I've also tried manually piping the streams (rather than using the `pipe` method itself) but the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry if I got this question wrong but it seems you are
trying to use encodings with a binary file. You don't need
to: node gives you raw buffers with binary data by default.

Here is an example of me downloading a clown:

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs   = require("fs");

http.get({ 
  host: "2.bp.blogspot.com", 
  path: "/_IR8qT_UKjOI/TT2P3qleU9I/AAAAAAAAA3I/beckWSLh3nk/s1600/clown.jpg" },
  function(res) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream("clown.jpg");
    res.pipe(stream);
  });
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check:
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1569

Node doesn't like newlines in http. Update your node.

If you are looking for couchdb I have a blog post on the subject on my blog at writings.nunojob.com. Using nano is usually a good choice as a couch client

Comment: I'm already using v0.4.12, upgrading and using v0.5.8 did not resolve the issue either.